# HTML form in ng-if environment

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-scope, parent-child, angular-ng-if

Structure of my app is like following:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" ng-if="showChild">
        <div class="child-view-1" ng-if="!isShown">
        </div>

        <div class="child-view-2" ng-if="isShown">
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Inside `child-view-2` I have form element, and of course, it is undefined in controller, probably beacuse of `ng-if`  (as it creates `child scope`).

`isShown` variable just switches divs from `child-view-1` to `child-view-2`.

What do you suggest, how can I make form visible all time in controller?

**EDIT: My fault, the outer child is controlled by `showChild` flag...**

Comment: Please share your controller for more precise help

Answer (score 0):

You have an outer `ng-if` (on `div class="child"`) based on the value of `isShown`. When isShown is true the content will be added to the DOM, and the `class="child-view-1"` will obviously not be added to the DOM because of `ng-if="!isShown"`

The second div's ng-if is redundant because it is the same condition as the outer one:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" ng-if="isShown">
        <div class="child-view-1" ng-if="!isShown">
<!-- THIS WILL NEVER BE DISPLAYED -->
        </div>

        <div class="child-view-2" ng-if="isShown">
<!-- THIS WILL ALWAYS BE DISPLAYED WHEN isShown IS TRUE -->
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```